# Finding why an Angular 5 service subscription is returning a null observable

Tags: java, angular, servlets, service, observable

I have the following service subscription in my component:

```
this.userService.loginUser(this.user).subscribe(users => {
  if (users == null) {
    console.log('users is null');
    this.isValid = !this.isValid;
  } else {
    this.userService.subscribers.next(users);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(users));
    console.log(`User, ${this.user.username}, successfully logged in!`);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
  }
});
```

The service method looks like this:

```
public loginUser(user: User) {
console.log(`Attempting to login user: ${user.username}`);
const json = JSON.stringify(user);
this.currentUser = user;
return this.http.post<User>(API_URL + 'login', json, HTTP_OPTIONS);
```

}

The post request goes to this java servlet method:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("login attempt");

    if (req.getInputStream() != null) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        User user = mapper.readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);
        user = userService.loginUser(user);


        if (user != null) {
            user.setPassword("");
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
        }
    }
}
```

On the java end, a username and password match is found and the session attribute is correctly set. However, on the Angular end, 'users' is null, as evidenced by the `console.log('users is null')` in the first code block. So my question is, why is this null? Can someone please help me understand the mechanics of this? I'm having a very hard time grasping how certain aspects of Angular even work...

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that in the servlet I didn't have a response. At the end I needed

```
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
out.write(mapper.writeValueAsString(user));
```